# Ajax, submitting form by using a link to the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

First i have a form and i can submit it with that code:

```
<form method="post" action="javascript:void(0);" id="productFrom<?php echo $x;?>">
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_ID']?>" name="I_ID" />
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Name']?>" name="I_Name" />
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Price']?>" name="I_Price" />
    <input type = "hidden" value="<?php echo $MenuItem['Item_Image']?>" name="I_img" />
</form>
<a class="view-link shutter" href="javascript: submitForm('<?php echo $x;?>');" name="Add">
<i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>Add To Cart</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(formID)
    {
        $('#productFrom'+formID ).submit();
    }

</script>
```

But i need to submit it to the same page and printing the form contents in specific div
with id"CART", so i have to use ajax

i tried this but does not work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(formID) {
    $('#productFrom'+formID ).submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax('getCartItems.php', str, function(result){
            // the result variable will contain any text echoed by getCartItems.php
            document.getElementById('CART').innerHTML = alert(result);
        }
        return(false);
    }););
}
</script>
```

My errors are:

```
*SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list //on return false line
*ReferenceError: submitForm is not defined
```

Comment: I think you better spend more some time to study JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its much easier to see where the syntax errors are when the code is properly formatted:

```
function submitForm(formID)
{
    $('#productFrom' + formID).submit(function () {
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax('getCartItems.php', str, function (result) {
            // the result variable will contain any text echoed by getCartItems.php
           $('#CART').html(result);

        });
        return false;
    });  
}
```

Comment: still does not work, i am not sure about the logic of the function